# Xamarin Forms ListView stays empty after filling the source

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created a ListView with as itemsource a List called unknownDeviceList from my ViewModel. Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class VM_AddDeviceList : BindableObject
{
    private List<UnknownDevice> _unknownDeviceList;
    public List<UnknownDevice> unknownDeviceList
    {
        get
        {
            return _unknownDeviceList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_unknownDeviceList != value)
            {
                _unknownDeviceList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public List<UnknownDevice> deviceList_raw;

    public VM_AddDeviceList()
    {
        deviceList_raw = new List<UnknownDevice>();
        unknownDeviceList = new List<UnknownDevice>();
        MyHandler();
    }

    private async Task LoadUnknownDeviceList()
    {
        deviceList_raw = await App.RestService.GetDevices();

        foreach (UnknownDevice device in deviceList_raw)
        {
            bool containsItem = App.knownDeviceList.Any(item => item.MAC == device.MAC);

            if (!containsItem)
            {
                unknownDeviceList.Add(device);
            }
        }
    }

    public Task MyHandler()
    {
        return LoadUnknownDeviceList();
    }
}
```

Now I can see that unknownDeviceList gets filled in the foreach, but on the screen the ListView stays empty. What am I doing wrong?
Something with the async and await?

Comment: Use an `ObservableCollection<>` instead of `List<>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are raising `PropertyChanged` when setting `unknownDeviceList` to inform the view that the list has changed. Anyway, there is no way for the view to know that there were items added to `unknownDeviceList`.

The most idiomatic way to solve the issue would be to use an [`ObservableCollection<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) instead.

```cs
private ObservableCollection<string> _unknownDevices = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public ObservableCollection<string> UnknownDevices => _unknownDevices;
```

**Please note** that I've used the [expression body syntax for read-only properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#read-only-properties) for `UnknownDevices`, it's not a field.

Since `ObservableCollection<string>` implements [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=netframework-4.8) which can be subscribed to by the binding to `UnknownDevices` the view is informed about the changes in `UnknownDevices` and will be updated when any items are added or removed.